# Unable to delete user.name from global config in git

Tags: git, github

Whenever I am trying to contact remote repo in git, I am getting bad response error(400). So, I did verified remote fetch and pull url's.

git remote -v // Those seems to be okay.

git config --global --edit user.name

git config --global --remove-all user.name

I verified global configuration on cmd prompt and It seems "user.name" entry apper as twice. I tried removing and modified this second entry. I am unable to delete problematic entry(one which is not matching from github) out of those entries. It seems it is picking up that configuration from some file. I am not able to locate that file. I vaguely recall modifying that sometime back. I checked config folder as well.

Comment: GitHub doesn’t care about your `user.name`, note. It’s just the name used when committing – typically your real name and not a username.

Comment: Did you check ~/.gitconfig ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, git checks .config file at couple of places like user config file(~/.gitconfig), local repo's config file (.git/config) and system specific config.

Alternatively, You can check and verify the location from where configuration is stored or picked from.

git config --global --show-origin

https://github.com/git/git/blob/70bd879ab66aeee809306908e3551d50cdf06802/Documentation/git-config.txt#L197-L201

Probably this will help you modifying git configuration. However I am not following your original motivation to modify this configuration.

Comment: thanks, user.name wasn't correct as per GitHub settings. which was resulting in fbad request. Not sure Why, but after removing that entry. It worked.